# C# WPF how to resize datagrid columns proportionally in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind, datagridcolumn

I have a datagrid whose column properties have to be changed programmatically in code behind for this I use the  event

```
AutoGeneratingColumn="Datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
```

on which I do:

```
 private void Datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  string strDatagridName = (sender as DataGrid).Name;
  switch (strDatagridName.ToUpper())
  {
    case "DTGPPTAB1":
    case "DTGPPTAB3":
      switch (e.PropertyName.ToUpper())
      {
        /*----Visible ----*/
        case "DESCRIPTION": e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.Description); e.Column.Width = 33; break;<-------------here
        case "NOTE": e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.Notes);  break;
        case "PARTPROGRAMFILENAME": e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.PPfilename);  break;

          /*----Hidden ----*/
        case "LSTBLADES": e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.Blades); break;
        case "LSTMYIMAGES": e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.Image); e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;  break;
        case "LSTMYSOUNDFILES": e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.Sound); e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; break;
        case "BARCODE": e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.Barcode); e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; break;
        case "PROGRAMTRACEFIELDS": e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.ProgramTracefields); e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; break;
        default: e.Column.Header = e.PropertyName; break;
      }
      break;
  }
```

and everything works fine.
What I'd need is in the DESCRIPTION case. Here I can set the column widht in pixels but I can't get to set it proportionally e.g. 33%.

So in short I'd like to get to set the first 3 columns to divide the whole datagrid space in 33% 33% 33%. So in % instead than in pixels.
Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the `Width` to a `double`, you need to set it to a `DataGridLength`. Here's an example:

```
e.Column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```

Setting these columns to `1*` should be enough to distribute the widths fairly (33% for 3 columns).

Comment: Yes, pretty much. It's all relative sizing. If they are all set to 1* then they will all be the same size relative to the size of the `DataGrid`.